# "Base Color" material menu missing when I open an older file

Tags: texturing, materials

I made a model with some older unknown blender version (don't remember which).
Now I'm trying to open it in blender 2.80.

My problem is that texture is missing, and when I try to open the Base Color menu, nothing pops up.
This is what happens when I click on the Base Color options circle when opening blender new file:
[image]

Which is good! But once I open my old blender file, this menu is missing and nothing opens.
How can I get my old model on new blender? Is this a bug or I need to change something?

Thanks,

Comment: so let me sum up .... u had an old file , u open 2.8 it opens up this menu , but this menu is missing in your old file??

Comment: Exactly. just wanted to emphasize that this menu does exist when I open blender, but the moment I load my file - its gone. Thanks

Comment: can you give me the file thorugh https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com , upload here and add link in question